# is it possible to Install Apache Bigtop Stack with Ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigtop

Can any one provide tutorial or steps to installing Apache BigTop stack using Ambari.

I have tried to learn the following info

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/Bigtop+1.3.0+Release

but what are the steps to install each of hadoop componet using amabri

I don't want to install using HDP stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jessica if you want to install custom services into ambari you have 2 options:

1. [Use/Make a custom Ambari Service](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Defining+a+Custom+Stack+and+Services)
2. [Create a Management Pack](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Management+Packs)

An example of #1:  [Hue Ambari Service](https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/HDP3-Hue-Service)

An example of #2:   [Management Pack for ELK](https://github.com/steven-dfheinz/dfhz_elk_mpack)

I use open source examples like HDF Management Pack or Custom Ambari Services found on GitHub and customize them to my needs.  Linked above, I have done this for Elasticsearch, HUE, NIFI and many other services.

Comment: Could you create a tutorial to custom Spark 3 in ambari 2.7.4 hdp 3.1.4? @steven-matison