# How to Add a Service to Ambari managed cluster (bigtop 3.2.1) , example : sqoop / sentry / kudu

Tags: hadoop, ambari, bigtop

I have successfully Implemented the [Bigtop project](https://bigtop.apache.org/download.html#releases), now i have a working Ambari managed cluster with the latest [Bigtop Stack](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/BIGTOP/Bigtop+3.2.1+Release) and i want to add a couple of services to my cluster such as Sqoop / Sentry / Kudu .

i searched for a documentation but it's either old or ambiguous, but i liked this answer [is it possible to Install Apache Bigtop Stack with Ambari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61654230/is-it-possible-to-install-apache-bigtop-stack-with-ambari) of user steven-matison but it still needs explanation, and i want to know if anyone of you have tried to either add a service or create a custom one, and can you provide steps to do so.

Comment: Sqoop isn't a service, it's a cli that submits jobs to yarn. It's also a retired Apache project, so you probably shouldn't be using it anymore

Comment: In any case, as shown in the linked answer, that's exactly what the Ambari documentation shows... If anything is unclear in the actual documentation or linked examples, you'll want to join Ambari users / developers mailing list... Alternatively, just use Ansible. There's no reason to use a UI tool to install Linux services

Comment: what do you mean by "use ansible" ? how does that relate to anything we are talking about, btw, i don't choose the components my company uses, if they use sqoop than i install sqoop, and if you have any idea how to do so, you could tell me, else, i don't really see how ansible has any relation to the subject.

Comment: BigTop dropped Sqoop because it is retired Apache project. Therefore, it cannot be installed anymore. If you need it installed, you need an alternative, such as Ansible, not using Ambari stacks. Ansible is commonly used to setup Linux machines; unclear what Ambari will be providing here. If your company otherwise uses Puppet, SaltStack, Terraform, etc then you can also use those