How to Add a Service to Ambari managed cluster (bigtop 3.2.0) EXAMPLE:IMPALA
I am using ambari 2.8 and bigtop 3.2.0 to build a big data platform. How can I add the Impala component to ambari for management?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61729635/2308683
